# should labor charge include waste percentage?

Tags: installation, carpet

The carpet company is charging so much per yard for the carpet, and labor included.  A 10% waste factor is added on.  That means I'm paying 10% more for the labor, right?  Is that normal?  I'm told by the company, 'that's how everyone does it.'

Similarly with a small tile job they will also do.  The job measures out to almost exactly 2 boxes of tile.  I have to pay for a third box of tile because of waste.  Understandable.  But the company also wants to charge labor for the whole box of tile.

I'm about to back out of this deal.

Comment: I could understand companies charging your for the waste, but tacking on the labor percentage to the waste factor seems sketchy.  They probably do it because calculating the square footage of the waste so they know the dollar amount to rebate you would just be too much trouble.

Comment: Get quotes from a few different contractors and see if they really do charge extra.

Comment: Most contractors would calculate labor using the actual square footage of the job, not the material purchased with overage. Get some other quotes.